# Most efficient way to find distinct records, retaining unique ID

Tags: sql

I have a large dataset stored in a SQL server table, with 1 unique ID, and many attributes. I need to select the distinct attribute records, along with one of the unique IDs associated with that unique combination.

Example dataset:

```
ID|Col1|Col2|Col3...
1|big|blue|ball
2|big|red|ball
3|big|blue|ball
4|small|red|ball
```

Example Goal (2,3,4 would also have been acceptable) :

```
ID|Col1|Col2|Col3...
1|big|blue|ball
2|big|red|ball
4|small|red|ball
```

I have tried a few different methods, but all of them seem to be taking very long (hours), so I was wondering if there was a more efficient approach. Failing this, my next idea is to partition the table.

I have tried:

1. Using Where exists, e.g.

   ```
   SELECT * from Table as T1
   where exists (select *
        from table as T2
         where
           ISNULL(T1.ID,'') <> ISNULL(T2.ID,'')
           AND ISNULL([T1].[Col1],'') = ISNULL([T2].[Col1],'')
           AND ISNULL([T1].[Col2],'') = ISNULL([T2].[Col2],'')
   )
   ```
2. MAX(ID) and Group By Attributes.
3. GROUP BY Attributes, having count > 1.

Answer (score 1):

How about just using `group by`?

```
select min(id), col1, col2, col3
from t
group by col1, col2, col3;
```

This will probably take a while.  This might be more efficient:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.id = (select min(t2.id)
              from t t2
              where t.col1 = t2.col1 and t.col2 = t2.col2 and . . .
             );
```

This requires an index on `t(col1, col2, col3, . . ., id)`.  Given your request, that is on all columns.

In addition, this will not work for columns that are `NULL`.  Some databases support the ANSI standard `is not distinct from` for null-safe comparisons.  If yours does, then it should use the index for this construct as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Id,Col1,Col2,Col3 FROM ( 
SELECT Id,Col1,Col2,Col3,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (Partition By Col1,Col2,Col3 Order By ID,Col1,Col2,Col3) valid
from Table as T1) t
WHERE valid=1
```

Hope this helps...